# wso2Analytics purge not removing data from analytics_event_store and analytics_processed_data_store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I want to remove the data from analytics_processed_data_store and analytics_event_store.

I have configured the purge and gave .*.

In the log I can observe so many tables with org_ where as in the database I am not able to find the tables

And the data from the analytics_processed_data_store and analytics_event_store has not been deleted

I want to delete the data from the above 2 databases since the size of those databases is very large.I dont want to remove any data from stats_db

Can any one help please

Thanks